# Need access to flask request context & db session after they exit

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a flask app that streams content out to the user, and I'm trying to manipulate the db while this streaming is happening. Here's some example code (simplified):

```
def work_hard(obj):
    yield 'About to do a lot of work...'
    obj.status = do_a_lot_of_work_very_slowly()
    yield obj.status
    db.session.commit()
    obj.more = more_slow_stuff()
    yield obj.more
    db.session.commit()
    yield 'Hard work is done!'

@app.route('/log/<int:objid>/work_hard', methods=['POST'])
def perform_action(objid):
    obj = MyModel.query.get(objid)
    return Response(work_hard(obj), mimetype='text/html')
```

This code gives the error `Instance <MyModel at 0x7f5555f046a0> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed`, but if I call `db.session.commit()` inside `perform_action()` instead of `work_hard()`, it works. Similarly, if I try to access flask's `request` instance, it works in `perform_action()` but not `work_hard()` (it complains that I'm trying to access the request outside of a request context).

I assume that these are both because `work_hard()` is executing after `perform_action()` has returned. Is is possible to somehow prolong the request context to include `work_hard()`? So far I've just been passing individual values from `request` to `work_hard()` and that worked to a point, but now I need to commit to the db and I'm not sure how to fix the db session here.

I can't just call `db.session.commit()` from `perform_action()`, I really do need to be able to make multiple updates in the db in real-time as the output is streaming to the HTTP client.

If this turns out not to be possible, my backup plan is to stream output from a subprocess, and then in the subprocess I'll connect to the db from there, but I'd prefer to do it all within the same process if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stream_with_context()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/#streaming-with-context) to keep the context (and hence the session) around while the generator runs:

```
return Response(stream_with_context(work_hard(obj)), ...)
```

Comment: This is it, thank you! Quick note for googlers in the future: My first attempt got me the dreaded `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such savepoint: sa_savepoint_1 [SQL: 'RELEASE SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_1']` and googling this suggested some pretty ugly workarounds, but those workarounds are for older versions of python. in python 3.5 at least, all i had to do was stop calling `db.session.begin_nested()` which was a failed experiment I'd forgotten to delete anyway. It works!

Answer (score 1):

Access the session with [application context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/appcontext/): `with app.app_context`

```
def work_hard(obj):
    yield 'About to do a lot of work...'
    obj.status = "blub"
    yield obj.status
    with app.app_context():
        db.session.commit()
    obj.more = "fish"
    yield obj.more
    with app.app_context():
        db.session.commit()
    yield 'Hard work is done!'

@app.route('/log/<int:objid>/work_hard', methods=['POST'])
def perform_action(objid):
    def perform_action(objid):
    obj = MyModel.query.get(objid)
    return Response(work_hard(obj), mimetype='text/html')
```